# How to render different UI contexts in a loop within a Django project?

Tags: python, django, loops, render

Suppose I have the following code:

```
async def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        number = "3"
        context = {"number": number}
        return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
```

I want to have a website that returns different values of the context "3", "2", "1" at the beginning of a game. It would be in a loop similar to this:

```
async def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        number = 3
        while int(number) < 1: 
           context = {"number": str(number)}
           render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
           time.sleep(1)
           number -= 1
```

The problem here is that I would think I'd need to return `render(request, 'home/home.html', context)`. But If I return that then I'll break the while loop. How can I then iterate through the values I'd like, and change the UI as required without breaking the loop?

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You need JavaScript for this. Django is for the *backend*, the thing that is done by the *server*. Not the *front end*, what the user sees, that is a combo of HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Could you please show me how that could be accomplished with javascript?